# NextJS, Typescript -> Write Data to Google Cloud Firestore Map (nested object)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, nested

I need your help. I am writing an application with NextJS(React), Typescript and Google Cloud Firestore. So far it works without any problems. However, I want to store the address and phone in a nested object in Firestore (Map). This is also created correctly in Firestore via my variables. I can access and set all variables in my inputs. Except the one from my nested object. I have tried many versions, but unfortunately I can't find the right solution. How can I access these variables in the "address" object in my form element in return (street, state, zip, etc) to set them.

My variables

```
const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState({
name: "",
description: "",
adress: {
  street: "",
  zip: 0,
  city: "",
  state: ""
},
phone: {
  phoneNumber: "",
  mobilePhoneNumber: "",
},
taxId: "",
generetedBy: currentUser.uid,
dateExample: serverTimestamp(),
//stringExample: "",
//booleanExample: true,
//numberExample: 3.14159265,
//arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
//nullExample: null,
```

});

My Submit Handler

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
e.preventDefault();

const colRef = collection(db, "restaurant");

await addDoc(colRef, formInput);

//formRef.current.reset()
```

};

My TextInput

```
<TextInput
      onChange={(e: any) =>
        setFormInput({
          ...formInput,
          adress.street: e.target.value,
        })
      }
      type="text"
      name="street-address"
      id="street-address"
      autoComplete="street-address"
      //value={formInput.adress.street}
    />
```

There i get an Error for "adress.street". This will not work as i was thinking... Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set like this

```
setFormInput({
      ...formInput,
      adress :{
         ...formInput.address,
         street: e.target.value,
     }
})
```

Comment: and uncomment the value attribute